# Iterating a dictionary with list values (why does it iterate over the list)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm starting with python

Why is it that the 'for' loop is iterating over the list and not over the key of the dictionary?

The intention is that the loop iterates over the list but I don't understand why it's happening if 'for' loops are supposed to iterate over the keys and not over the values

```
def getUserData():
    D = {}
    while True:
        studentId = input("Enter student ID: ")
        gradesList = input("Enter the grades by comma separated values: ")
        moreStudents = input("Enter 'no' to quit insertion or 'yes' to add more student info: ")
        if studentId in D:
            print(studentId, "is already inserted")
        else:
            D[studentId] = gradesList.split(",")
        if moreStudents.lower() == "no":
            return D
        elif moreStudents.lower() == "yes":
            pass


studentData = getUserData()


def getAvgGrades(D):
    avgGrades = {}
    for x in D:
        L = D[x] <------------------- #This is specifically what I don't understand
        s = 0
        for grades in L:
            s = s + int(grades)
        avgGrades[x] = s/len(L)
    return avgGrades


avgG = getAvgGrades(studentData)


for x in avgG:
    print("Student:", x, "got avg grades as: ", avgG[x])
```

Comment: Hint: In your `for` loop `print(x)` above `L = D[x]` to see what `x` actually equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over a dict like so:

```
for x in D:
```

You actually do this:

```
for x in D.keys(): # you iterate over the keys
```

To get the key and the value, simply do this:

```
for k, v in D.items():
```

Comment: @DarioDefosse `items` is a function. You need to call it. So instead of `for x in D.items:` do `for x in D.items(): `. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Oh now I see, I believe I need 15 reputation to cast the vote :(, but I do appreciate the help a lot!!

Comment: Aight, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop iterates over the keys of a `dict`. So this code:

```py
for x in D:
    L = D[x]
```

Means that `x` is each key from the `D`.

Then `L = D[x]` fetches the corresponding list generated previously: `D[studentId] = gradesList.split(",")`

Better would be to iterate over the keys and values at once:

```py
for x,L in D.items():
    s = 0
    ...
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm not able to understand correctly, why is it that L = D[x] fetches the list if "x" is each key and not the list? I appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: The whole point of a `dict` is to be able to start with just a key (`x` in your case) and be able to fetch some other value. The syntax for that is the square brackets: `D[x]`. Your code as posted is already using this syntax to set the other value: `D[studentId] = gradesList.split(",")`